# clip-path: polygon on Firefox

Tags: css

I used search for my problem, but I couldn't find any similar question. 
I have prblem with CSS on Firefox. 
"clip-path:" doesn't show. 
Here is my code of HTML and CSS.

```css
.path {
 display: block;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
 -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0px 170px, 100% 0px,100% 650px,0px 900px);
 clip-path: polygon(0px 170px, 100% 0px,100% 650px,0px 900px);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://www.valueinvestasia.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/stock-market-2.jpg" class="path"/>
```

Comment: maybe this tells you why it doesn't work (yet) ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path

Comment: As you see, I used same code like on this link. And that is problem.

Comment: For FF, it applies to non graphics SVG elemnts nor <defs>, here you use HTML tag (as the link says :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a problem of compatibility, as states the [**documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility)
for this css proprety : `clip-path: polygon()`
make sure that you're using a mozilla firefox version with the Gecko enging
it seems to work fine for the web-kit

a [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/AmineTbaik/vLgk6f0j/) link of your work, matching it with different browsers in browserstack.com gives you [this](https://www.browserstack.com/screenshots/e63d11b2675991aea6addbc57b388e9243ec4a64)